# Django refresh page

Tags: python, ajax, django

I can not figure out how to change the page without rebooting with Ajax.

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('name/', views.name, name='name'),
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
  ]
```

**views.py**

```
def name(request):
    return render(request, 'site/name.html')
```

**index.html**

```
<a href="/name" id="aj">page name</a>

<div id="content">
   {% block content %}
   {% endblock %}
</div>
```

**I will be very grateful if you will give me a simple code.**

Comment: What do you mean by "change the page" ? What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: there are two pages index.html, two.html I need to click the link to load the second page two.html in the {% block content%} through ajax

Comment: you don't need block tag, if you change content with ajax. You could call ajax and change content simply..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try whit this..

views.py

```
def page_name(request):
    return render(request, 'site/name.html', {})
```

urls.py

```
from .views import index, page_name
urlpatterns = [
  path('name/', page_name, name='name'),
  path('', index, name='index'),
]
```

index.html

```
<a href="#" id="clickme">page name</a>

{% block content %}
    <div id="content">
        <!-- Your content -->
    </div>
{% endblock content %}


<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#clickme').click(function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        synch: 'true',
        type: 'GET',
        url: '{% url 'name' %}',
        success: function(data){
            $('#content').html(data);
        }
    });//End Ajax
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Tell me how to change url. when the page is updated (F5), everything is discounted.

Comment: What do you mean with change the url?

Comment: Your example works, I added

var url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/forms/"
history.pushState (undefined, '', url);

but did not avoid the problem, when you press the button F5 or update the page, Ajax is reset and we see the start page without the loaded block

Answer (score 0):

if your view return html, you could do like this,

```
var post_data = {
    'field1':x,
    'field2':y,
    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': "{{ csrf_token }}"
};

$.post("{% url "urlname" %}", post_data, function(result){
    $("#content").html(result);
})
```